# Kotlin upgrade causes DefaultWhiteList loading issue

Tags: corda

Am I correct in observing that Corda 1.0 is using Kotlin plugin 1.1.4? Just out of interest I tried to use 1.1.51 and ran into defaultWhiteList loading issues...although I'm not entirely sure why tbh...suspect classpath loading issues on the ServiceLoader.load in DefaultKryonCustomizer?? Anyway, when I revert to 1.1.1 (am still on M13) all is well again.

Just wanted to gain some understanding around why an inadvertent upgrade of the Kotlin plugin to 1.1.51 would cause issues with the serialisation default whitelist loading?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat non-answer, but I'll try anyway: As we see the kotlin language mature and as Corda uses quite a wide feature set of what's available in kotlin, it doesn't surprise me that sometimes the frequently published newer versions of Kotlin don't work with older versions of Corda - especially if they make some internal changes to objects then I'm not surprised we see kryo serialisation issues.  We publish the recommended / supported version of kotlin in the `constants.properties` file which, for release 1, is as you've correctly pointed out, 1.1.4 (which can be confirmed here: https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/e564edaa572a011869d692b05518113632363216/constants.properties ).

It does look as if we have updated this for the forthcoming v2 release to 1.1.50 if that helps. It may be a little late in the day to bump this to 1.1.51 though (a fair amount of testing and QA has already been performed).

Comment: Yes that's a useful response thank-you. The "empty-list not on the default white list" typifies a module loading issue; usually manifesting itself upon getProtocolVersion call on first RPC communication. I associate that now with a module incompatibility / loading problem; in this case wrong version of Kotlin.